# How to move an element in layout using keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have the following RadioGroup with 3 radio buttons:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editCode">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioQr"
        android:layout_width="63dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/qrLabel" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioCard"
        android:layout_width="89dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tarjetaLabel" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioRemoteOrder"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pedidoLabel" />

</RadioGroup>
```

The fact is that the radio buttons fit exactly the radio group, which, in turn, is centered horizontally.

This is perfect, however, I have problems when creating constraints. When I create a constraint for the RadioGroup with respect to the control above it, the radio group (and its radio buttons) move to that control. Now I need to move the radio group down, however, since radio buttons fit exactly, when I select a RadioGroup and then try to move it, a radio button is selected so only a radio button is moved.

I think the only way to move the RadioGroup is by mean of the keyboard. I tried to use arrow keys but it did not work.

How can I do it (of course, in design view)?

Thanks
Jaime